# Net for both cube and regular tetrahedron

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polyhedra

At [how to fold it](http://howtofoldit.org/) by Joseph O'Rourke, there is a net given that can be folded into a [cube or irregular tetrahedron](http://howtofoldit.org/Images/LatinCrossTetra.pdf).

Is there a net that can be folded into either a cube or regular tetrahedron?

Comment: That is: a cube or *regular* tetrahedron?

Comment: I gave a solution for an irregular tetrahedron -- but I've gone ahead and added the word "regular" to the problem specification.